# Cannot read property 'paginationOption' of undefined in React Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeahead, react-bootstrap-typeahead

In the `todos` array, it looks for an element with`id 4`. He writes it to the `owner` variable. I put the `owner` variable in the`newArray` array. Then, I put `newArray` in`selected = {newArray.slice (0, 1)}`. I want to display `owner` as default in input. I use library: `React Bootstrap Typeahead`.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-agfvwn?file=index.js

I have error:

> Cannot read property 'paginationOption' of undefined

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  getTodos = () => {
    axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({
        todos: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.todos)
    const owner = this.state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === 4)

    const newArray = [];
    newArray.push(owner)

    return (
      <div>
        <Typeahead
          id={'sasas'}
          selected={newArray.slice(0,1)}
          labelKey="title"
          options={this.state.todos}
          ref={(ref) => this._typeahead = ref}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @barbsan The error has disappeared, but the input is empty by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your owner is `undefined` on initial render since `getTodos` has not yet finished and `this.state.todos` is empty array.

You should set your selected item once your data is fetched, for example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      selected: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTodos().then(() => {
      const todo = this.state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === 4);
      this.setState({
        selected: todo ? [todo] : []
      })
    })

  }

  getTodos = () => {
    return axios({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({
        todos: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Typeahead
          id={'sasas'}
          selected={this.state.selected}
          labelKey="title"
          options={this.state.todos}
          ref={(ref) => this._typeahead = ref}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```